Is Mtd-utils common library considered to be LGPL?
When you need to use the common library of mtd-utils in the embedded development process, but don't want to open source your own code, what can you do? Is this common library considered to be licensed under LGPL?
If it is LGPL, it is a good way to develop it into a dynamic library and call it directly from the application.

What does its license or readme file say? Your question allows use of links, so do link the library you talk about

What makes you believe lgpl applies?

Have you ever considered looking at the most obvious place to understand the license of mtd-utils?

Several source code files I want to use show that they need to meet the GPL. Like https://github.com/lgirdk/mtd-utils/blob/master/lib/libmtd.c

It is a tool, so the open source code is compiled into a tool software, and we only want the function of nandflash to read and write and jump bad blocks.


When you need to use the common library of mtd-utils in the embedded development process, but don't want to open source your own code, what can you do?

You have the normal options:

Redevelop the functionality from scratch. However, you have somewhat compromised your position here by looking at the mtd-utils code, which could lead to claims that your work is based on mtd-utils and these may be difficult for you to show that it wasn't.
Negotiate a separate license with the mtd-utils copyright holders.


Is this common library considered to be licensed under LGPL?

No, it is licensed under the GPL as you are well aware.

Yeah, I think so too, I'll try to find the copyright holder. Thank you.
